# how to make a public property even with underscore in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, json-serialization, built-value

I'm fetching some json data from a rest api server and one of its keys is `_id` and I need to serialize this json to a dart object using built_value, but this isn't allowed because in dart `_id` is private and built_value doesn't allow me to define a private getter in my model!
So what do I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`package:built_value` has a mechanism to rename fields.  As mentioned in its [`README.md`](https://pub.dev/packages/built_value#common-usage):

> The corresponding dart class employing `built_value` might look like this. Note that it is using ... the `@BuiltValueField` annotation to map between the property name on the response and the name of the member variable in the `Person` class.
>
> ```dart
>   ...
>
>   @nullable
>   @BuiltValueField(wireName: 'first_name')
>   String get firstName;
> ```

So in your case, you should be able to do something like:

```dart
@BuiltValueField(wireName: '_id')
String get id;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can replace `'_id'` with `'id'` once you got JSON Response String. Then serialize it.

Model Class :

```
@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class PersonModel{
  int id;
  String name;

  PersonModel(this.id,this.name);

  factory PersonModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$PersonModel FromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$PersonModelToJson(this);
}
```

Replace :

```
String responseString = response.body
String newResponseString = responseString.replaceAll('_id', 'id');
PersonModel personModel = PersonModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(newResponseString));
```

Now you can use `personModel.id` to access `_id` in frontend.

Comment: yes it works, but the best way to do it is to use `@BuiltValueField(wireName: "_id")` attribute